# Getting error on Sci-Kit learn with loading IRIS Dataset

Tags: scikit-learn

I am getting an error for the following code

```
    `from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris=load_iris()
X=iris.(data)
y=iris.(target)
```

File "", line 3
    X=iris.(data)`
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `X = iris.data`, `Y=iris.target`

Comment: Okay, now I know this code will not work, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I am having trouble with the parenthesis transitioning from python 2 to 3, Thanks again

Comment: Please see this example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-datasets-plot-iris-dataset-py